# Malformed function or procedure escape syntax at offset 1

Tags: java, database, eclipse, postgresql, stored-procedures

I executed a code in eclipse and my objective is to call a stored procedure in postgres database. I tried with values passed from servlet and got this error:
" Malformed function or procedure escape syntax at offset 1."

so now I tried hardcoding the values . Still the same problem. What is offset? please help me to resolve the error. Iv already checked the order and datatype of fields.They are correct.

```
public int  dispCustomer3(Cust cc){
    con=dbCon.getConnection();
    //PreparedStatement ps3=null;
    System.out.println("inside update function ");
    CallableStatement callableStatement =null;
    try {
        callableStatement=con.prepareCall("{SELECT fn_UpdateCustomer(37, 'Test_Customer56','Test_Customer56','Requirement','Customer_Location',NULL,2,2,NULL,'Customer_Contact_Info','Account_Contact_Info','01-02-2016','01-04-2016',5,'Comments',1,2);}");
        /*callableStatement.setInt(1,cc.getCustId());
        callableStatement.setString(2,cc.getShortName());
        callableStatement.setString(3,cc.getStatus_name() );
        callableStatement.setString(4,cc.getRequirement());
        callableStatement.setString(5,cc.getCustomer_location());
        callableStatement.setInt(6,cc.getDemo_location_type_id());
        callableStatement.setInt(7, cc.getDeployment_type_id());
        callableStatement.setInt(8, cc.getRequested_by_id());
        callableStatement.setInt(9, cc.getPilot_resource_id());
        callableStatement.setString(10, cc.getCustomer_contact_info());
        callableStatement.setString(11, cc.getAccount_contact_info());
        callableStatement.setDate(12, cc.getDemo_planned_on());
        callableStatement.setDate(13, cc.getDemo_actual_on());
        callableStatement.setInt(14, cc.getStatus_id());
        callableStatement.setString(15, cc.getComments());*/
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
        callableStatement.executeUpdate();



    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{dbCon.closeConnection(con);}
    return 1;



}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `CallableStatement` you should `CALL` your procedure, rather than `SELECT`. Something like:

```
callableStatement=con.prepareCall("{CALL fn_UpdateCustomer(37, 'Test_Customer56','Test_Customer56','Requirement','Customer_Location',NULL,2,2,NULL,'Customer_Contact_Info','Account_Contact_Info','01-02-2016','01-04-2016',5,'Comments',1,2)}");
```

The error that you get, `Malformed function or procedure escape syntax at offset 1` refers to the `SELECT` keyword.

Comment: I made that change. But now Im getting :"Malformed function or procedure escape syntax at offset 203"

Comment: that means, that you solved the current issue, and a new arose at character #203 of your Connection.prepareCall() argument. Try dropping the ';' at the end of the argument, and see if that solves your issue. You can debug your code by checking the reported offset, each time.

Comment: In order to check the e.g. #203 character, you can copy-paste your code in a Notepad++ or a Sublime Text 2 or any other semi-smart editor!

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/81/callproc.html
and it works for me finely/

Good luck!